# Error says I'm missing paratheses but I checked and I can not find them

Tags: javascript

It keeps saying:

> Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) You might be missing a ( or have an extra )

But I can't find the extra `)`.

```
function start(){
    if (frontIsClear()){
        move();
    }else{
        if (frontIsBlocked()){
            jumpHurdle();
        }
    }

    function jumpHurdle()){
    turnLeft();
    move();
    turnRight();
    move();
    turnRight();
    move();
    turnLeft();
}
```

Comment: the start function is not closed. add a } before jumpHurdle declaration

Comment: Your extra `)` is here:    `function jumpHurdle()){`

Comment: you have an extra `)` as everyone else pointed out, but you are also missing a `}` ... nobody has noticed both problems :p

Comment: by the way, I chuckled at the title of the question `Error says I'm missing paratheses but I checked and I can not find them` ... if it's missing, of course you can't find it :p

Comment: You should absolutely install a linter to help you find which parenthesis is missing and other problems before runtime, check out https://eslint.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your extra parenthesis.

```
function jumpHurdle()){
                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the problem:

After jumpHurdle()**)**
There is one extra bracket.

It should be like this

```
function jumpHurdle(){
    turnLeft();
    move();
    turnRight();
    move();
    turnRight();
    move();
    turnLeft();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem -

```
function jumpHurdle()){
```

You must remove ")"